# Append string to binding

Tags: wpf, vb.net

In my VB.net application i need to show some images in some rectangle.
I have dataset which i use to display itemNumber and itemName in listbox.

This is my xml for listbox:

```
<ListBox x:Name="rrList" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource grList}">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="GrupeIzbornik">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Rectangle Height="64" Width="64"
                 Margin="2" >
                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding itemNumber}"/>
                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                </Rectangle>
                <Label Content="{Binding itemName}"
                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                 FontSize="14" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

Instead of "{Binding itemNumber}" i need something like Images\"{Binding itemNumber}".jpg, this is of course not correct syntax and it's the best way i could describe what i'm trying to achieve.

Comment: So do you want VB or C#?

Comment: @maccettura i have edited tags on my question, and I guess it's same thing actually. Could use any answer

Comment: Use a Binding [Converter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter(v=vs.110).aspx) that converts an item number to an ImageSource (e.g. a BitmapImage).

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

`<ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Path=itemNumber, StringFormat='Images\{0}\.jpg'}"/>`

Comment: This doesn't work. Why was it accepted as answer?